# Is it possible to replace an array by list of variables in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm in a situation where I need to define a function "fun" in terms of variables s12 and s23. Then in main function, I need to replace these variables (s12 and s23) by array "arr[ ]" defined in function "mn1". Example is here,

```
int fun(int s12, int s23)
{                                                                                                                                       
   int x=s12+s23;
}

int* mn(int* ar, int p[ ], int q[ ])
{
   ar[0]=p[0]*q[0];
   ar[1]=p[1]*q[1];
   return ar;
}

int main()
{
   int p[2]={4,2};
   int q[2]={1,3};
   int s12, s23;
   int ar[2];
   int* mn1= mn(ar, p, q);
   int Fun=fun(s12,s23);
   int D=Fun+s12;
   cout<<D<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Is there an error when you run the code?

Comment: Turn on all your warnings with `-Wall` and fix everything the compiler complains about.

Comment: what does `fun` return?

Comment: Yes, if I assign mn1[1] = s12, and mn1[2]=s23 (but I have not shown it in code), then compiler shows some random number like "293353623".

Comment: Please add all details, such as expected output, etc, to the question, instead of as a comment. Also, where in your code are you modifying `s12`, and `s23`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scenario shown in your code is extremely simple, so you shouldn't overthink it. The function `mn` is modifying the elements of its `ar` parameter, which correspond to elements of the `ar` array in `main`. So, just pass the elements of `ar` into the call to `fun`:

```
int Fun=fun(ar[0],ar[1]);
```

You can even ignore the return value of `mn`, since it just returns a copy of the pointer you passed in. Don't bother declaring `s12`, `s23`, and `mn1`. You might redesign this to get rid of the pointer (since it destroys information about the size of the array), but that's a matter for a different question.